# How to set div center vertically

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align div element centre vertically using below code but it's not working I am trying to get this since a long time but no result can someone help me please where did I do my stack and how can I

```css
.center {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border: 3px solid green;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Center Vertically</h2>
    <p>In this example, we use the padding property to center the div element vertically:</p>
    
    <div class="center">
      <p>I am vertically centered.</p>
      <form action="/action_page.php">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal information:</legend>
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

solve this?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FYB6T0NY6DTE

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .center {
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px 0;
      border: 3px solid green;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Center Vertically</h2>
    <p>In this example, we use the padding property to center the div element vertically:</p>
    
    <div class="center">
      <p>I am vertically centered.</p>
      <form action="/action_page.php">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal information:</legend>
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: did you check ?

Comment: not working your check my link

Comment: @Ramon de Vries: https://codepen.io/asiyafatima_12/pen/KbgBGd check this URL hope this will work.